# Installing windows in ubuntu with virtualbox

Tags: virtualbox

My desktop is running two OSes, windows 8.1 64-bit and Ubuntu 14.10 64-bit. But I want to run windows in Ubuntu instead of switching between them all the time. So I am now trying to install windows 8.1 (using the same windows disc and product key) in Ubuntu with virtualbox. While installing, I am given the options of "upgrade: will move all files, settings, applications to windows directory" or "custom: install windows only, will NOT move files, settings, applications to windows directory".

Which one should I choose?

Does the first option "upgrade" means it will copy the settings and installed applications of the windows I have been using to the new windows in virtualbox, so that I need not, e.g., install MS office again? That sounds great if true.

Comment: Please notice that this question is a bit off-topic on Askubuntu, because it doesn't relate directly to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the second, "custom" option.

By default, your virtual machine doesn't have access to real partitions on your hard drive. You probably can change this in your VM's options, but I'm not sure that it will work as expected (because I've never tried to do it :)).